# Executing asynchronous processing function from nested loops in order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that saves large batch of data in database. A callback will be called asynchronously at the end.

```
function process(..., fn) {
  saveInDB(function(err, results) {
    // ...
    // fn() or fn(err)
  })
}
```

The function is called multiple times from nested loops.

```
for (const x of arrays) {
  const space1 = x[0]
  for (const y of x.slice(1)) {
    const space2 = y[0]
    for (const z of y[1]) {
      process(space1, space2, z, fn)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem requires that the next invocation happens only if the previous succeeded. Here my cumbersome implementation.

```
let calls = []
for (const x of arrays) {
  const space1 = x[0]
  for (const y of x.slice(1)) {
    const space2 = y[0]
    for (const z of y[1]) {
      calls.push((fn) => () => process(space1, space2, z, fn))
    }
  }
}

let call = null

for (let i = calls.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {

  if (i === calls.length - 1) {
    call = calls[i](err => {
      if (!err)
        return finalCallback(null, { 'status': 'success' })
      log.error(err)
      finalCallback(err)
    })
    continue
  }

  const lastNext = call
  call = calls[i](err => {
    if (!err)
      return lastNext()
    finalCallback(err)
    log.error(err)
  })
}

if (call)
  call()
```

I am seeking for an advise from Javascript professionals how do you solve this kind of problems?

Comment: *The problem requires that the next invocation happens only if the previous succeeded.* That sounds synchronous, not asynchronous, to me.

Comment: I think you can achieve this with async/await.  Please let us know if you try it and it works.

Comment: `Async/await`? You can await while the asynchronous function finishes and only then proceed further.

Comment: You don't pass any data to `saveInDB`? Then what gets saved?

Comment: @JohnWu OP is looking for a *sequential* asynchronous execution.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the clarification. @all Will `async/await` work let's say for `fetch` instead of `saveToDB` in browser for a similar case?

Comment: @Yuki In fact it works much better on `fetch` than `saveToDB` since `fetch()` returns a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `async ... await`

In your use case, using the `await` keyword would allow you to wait for the promise returned by `process` to resolve before continuing. You will have to define your function as `async`.

You will also need to use a `try ... catch` block to handle any errors.

Since your `process` function does not currently return a promise you will need to modify it to do so.

Example:

```js
function process(/* your args */) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    saveInDB((err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(results)
      }
  })
}

// now for the `async ... await`
async function myFunc(arrays) {
  for (const x of arrays) {
    const space1 = x[0]
    for (const y of x.slice(1)) {
      const space2 = y[0]
      for (const z of y[1]) {
        try {
          // This will wait until your `process` has finished
          await process(space1, space2, z, fn)
        } catch (error) {
          // handle any errors
          console.log(error)
          // if you would like to bail after an error you can `return`
          return
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now that your function exists you can use it, however, it is asynchronous so it will not stop any code after it from running so you should do one of two things:

1. `await` your call to `myFunc` or
2. Place any code that relies on `saveInDB` to finish first in `.then()`

```js
myFunc(/* your arrays */)
  .then(() => {
    // your function has finished
  })
```

Comment: Will `async/await` work let's say for `fetch` instead of `saveToDB` in browser for a similar case?

Comment: @Yuki, yes `async ... await` works with fetch as well, because it returns a promise

Answer (score 1):

`saveToDB` would normally take some argument representing the data; I will just assume that it takes one data argument and a callback, but adapt as needed.

First promisify that function. Possibly the API you use might already support promises, meaning that the above function would return a promise if the callback function is not passed to it. But if this is not the case, you can create your own promisified function:

```
// promisify the saveInDB function:
const process = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    saveInDB(data, (err, results) => err ? reject(error) : resolve(results))
);
```

Then create an `async` function so that you can use `await`:

```
async function task(arrays) {
    for (const x of arrays) {
        const space1 = x[0]
        for (const y of x.slice(1)) {
            const space2 = y[0]
            for (const z of y[1]) {
                await process([space1, space2, z])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and call it. It returns a promise, so you can deal with fulfilment and rejection:

```
task(arrays).then(() => console.log("all done"))
            .catch((err) => console.log("error occurred", err));
```